# Need a Function to Return Multiple Types of Game Objects That I Can Call Methods On

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have a function return a generic game object that I can then call a method on. This doesn't work.

I have different objects in my game world. I'd like to have one function I can call that will return the object that was found at a given location. Then, check what type of object was found. Each of my objects has a GetObjectType method that returns the type of object.

I greatly appreciate any help you can send my way. Thanks for looking.

```
GameObject spotObjectLocation1;

spotObjectLocation1 = GetObjectAtLocation(player.transform.position 
                                          + checkDirection);

// THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO THAT DOESN'T WORK
if (spotObjectLocation1.GetObjectType() == "box"){  }

GameObject GetObjectAtLocation(Vector3 location)
{
    GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("boxes");

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objects[i].transform.position.x == location.x 
            && objects[i].transform.position.z == location.z)
        {
            return objects[i];
        }
    }

    GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("blocks");

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objects[i].transform.position.x == location.x 
            && objects[i].transform.position.z == location.z)
        {
            return objects[i];
        }
    }
}

public class ObjectBox : MonoBehaviour {    
    public string GetObjectType()
    {
        return "box";   
    }
}

public class ObjectBlock : MonoBehaviour {  
    public string GetObjectType()
    {
        return "block"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work means? Some error? What error in case? Or wrong results? Did you debug to see what does the function `GetObjectAtLocation` return?

Comment: Your function returns `GameObject`. does it have `GetObjectType` defined on that class? I guess you need a return type of `MonoBehaviour`. How is `GameObject` related to `MonoBehaviour`?

Comment: I am not sure if you really need that `GetObjectType` function in each class. You have a more strongly typed option already in `GetType` by default. Or better override the `ToString` function to have some sort of a string representation

Answer (score 2):

What exactly doesn't work?

Anyway, using proper inheritance trees and the "as" operator would be better. For example, have all your box objects inherit from a class Box (if there is more than one box object):

```
public class Box : GameObject
{
    ...
}

public class ObjectBox : Box
{
    ...
}
```

Then you can use the "as" operator to find out whether a GameObject is a box:

```
GameObject spotObjectLocation1 = GetObjectAtLocation(player.transform.position + checkDirection);

Box b = spotObjectLocation1 as Box;
if (b != null)
    ...
```

Also, this type of code is sometimes better handled with normal polymorphism. Think of what you would do with the object if it actually turns out to be a Box. Is it something you would also want to do with other types of objects? If so, have all those objects inherit from a common base class that provides virtual or abstract methods which the derived classes possibly override. Then the client code can simply call those methods through the base class without needing to know what is the actual type of the object.